# Moving an object along two axes instead of one

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, 3d-manipulator

One of my friends uses 3DS Max a lot, and he showed me when he was working that there are "angles" on his 3D manipulator that allow him to move (translate) objects in two axes at the same time. Looks something like this:
[image: manipulator in 3DS Max]

By clicking the square between X and Y for example, you can move the object around on X and Y and **not** on Z.

My 3D manipulator in Blender doesn't have that:
[image: manipulator in blender]

Therefore, moving an object along 2 axes requires 2 steps, which is more tedious than being able to do it in 1.

***Is there a way to enable bi-directional transformation on the manipulator?***

Comment: it stems from a rather spartan approach to ui. Some work has been done to recode blender's translate widget ( http://code.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/widgets_07.png ) see https://code.blender.org/2015/09/the-custom-manipulator-project-widget-project/ - not sure when or if that will be part of regular Blender ..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you press <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> you can move bi-directional in x-y direction.

You can do that also using manipulator - click on the white circle around manipulator's origin and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> as in the first case.

Comment: Here's what it does when I do that, not the expected behavior: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z50W__G5FSI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @fabriced you most likely have some snapping mechanism enabled. You can toggle that with *Shift-Tab*.

Comment: I think I was just pressing SHIFT + Z too long, one press is ok :)

Answer (score 5):

You can shift-click on the axis that should not move.

Comment: Ok, that works. A bit complex, I'll see if someone adds another answer, maybe an addon exists... we'll see

Comment: @fabriced you should consider marking your question as answered anyways if it helped you out. Other people with different solutions can still answer and you can later "unmark" that "as answered" and mark a different answer.

Comment: It's generally a bad strategy to do that right away, unless you really like the answer. It does discourage others from answering.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the object with  
press <*axis to exclude*> IE exclude Z: 
use the mouse to float to or the arrow keys to move it to the desired location and click to secure.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand. But imagine I have a view that is almost a top view, and want to move along Y and X only, that means I have to click the Z arrow, which will be hard to do since I'm viewing from above... Know what I mean? I mean maybe there's another way... Maybe not... Thanks a lot anyways

Comment: When you just press G the movement automatically occurs in the plane that is perpendicular to the view. This is also true for rotation but not for scale!